# How is CTRL+C handled in jline2

Tags: java, unix, sigint, shutdown-hook, jline

I had a hard time trying to understand how is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handled in jline2. I found in `consoleReader.readline` an exception will be thrown if `handleUserInterrupt` is set to true. But I wonder before this exception is thrown, how is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is trapped and interpreted (instead of exiting the program)?

Comment: a. this sort of Q is out-of-scope for Stackoverflow. b. you're also expecting people to either know what `jline2` is or to go and research it AND then dive into the code to explain it to you. Edit your Q to include links to the project, the relevant code that you're refering to (and its location in the project (/path/to/filename)) and you might get some help. Good luck?

Comment: Start reading the source code [around here](https://github.com/jline/jline2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=handleUserInterrupt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UserInterruptException` will be thrown only from one of the `ConsoleReader.readLine` methods and only when the user press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and `handleUserInterrupt` is set to true (by calling `consoleReader.setHandleUserInterrupt(true)`).

### On UNIX Platforms

Only if the terminal of the `ConsoleReader` is an instance of `UnixTerminal` (the default terminal for UNIX platforms), it's `disableInterruptCharacter` method is called when `readLine` is called. This method disables the default behavior of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (usually causes the JVM to exit) by executing proper command to the system (by using `stty`). Before the `readLine` method returns, it calls the `enableInterruptCharacter` method of the terminal, which enables the default behavior of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

This means that the default behavior of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is disabled only when the `readLine` method is executing.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks.